# PowerShell find and replace in different directories

Tags: powershell, replace, find

I am trying to make my PS script look in the directory as follows...

```
C:\FAKEENV
 └───DEVbox
    ├───PRD
    |    └──BatFile.txt
    └───STG
         └──BatFile.txt
```

What I am trying to do is see if either .txt has changed in the past 12 hours. If they have, replace a string in the bat file from 'dev' to 'stg' in the STG folder and 'stg' to '' (nothing) in the PRD folder.  I have changed variable and manipulated my code for hours with no luck.  I know my logic is just wrong because when I step through it never gets to the if statement that will manipulate the bat files.

```
Clear-Host
$date = Get-Date
$hours = '-12'    

#$StgDestFile = 'C:\FakeEnv\DEVbox\STG'
#$PrdDestFile = 'C:\FakeEnv\DEVbox\PRD'
$dest_file = 'C:\FakeEnv\DEVbox'

foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $dest_file -Recurse))
{
  #Check for changes from last $hours
  if($file.LastWriteTime -gt ($date).AddHours($hours))            
  {
      if($file -eq 'STG')
      {
        (Get-Content $dest_file\STG\BatFile.txt) | Foreach-Object {
          $_ -replace 'dev', 'stg' `
          #Format: -replace 'SOMETHING', 'SOMETHING ELSE' `                   
        } | Set-Content $dest_file    
        #Insert logic for uninstall and install of 'feature'
        #Insert logic for confirmation message of changes
      }
      elseif($file -eq 'PRD')    
      {
        (Get-Content $dest_file\PRD\BatFile.txt) | Foreach-Object {
          $_ -replace 'dev', 'stg' `
          #Format: -replace 'SOMETHING', 'SOMETHING ELSE' `                   
        } | Set-Content $dest_file    
        #Insert logic for uninstall and install of 'feature'
        #Insert logic for confirmation message of changes    
      }
    }
  }
  #If no changes occurded, log that nothing happened       
  else
  {
    $LogDestination = 'C:\FakeEnv\Logs'
    $LogPathExist = Test-Path "$LogDestination"
    #Do this if folder does not exist
    #If the folder has not already been created, create it and write to log file
    if($LogPathExist -eq $false)
    {
      New-Item $LogDestination -ItemType directory
      New-Item $LogDestination\log.log -ItemType file
      Add-Content $LogDestination\log.log "Script detected no changes in $dest_file on $date"
    }
    #Do this is folder does exist
    #if the folder exists, append to log file
    else
    {
      Add-Content $LogDestination\log.log "`nScript detected no changes in $dest_file on $date"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First ensure you only get files with the `-File` switch for `Get-ChildItem` (PS v3), then get the folder name and run your tests against it:

```
Clear-Host

$date = Get-Date
$hours = '-12'
#$StgDestFile = 'C:\FakeEnv\DEVbox\STG'
#$PrdDestFile = 'C:\FakeEnv\DEVbox\PRD'
$dest_file = 'C:\FakeEnv\DEVbox'

#get files only
foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $dest_file -File -Recurse)) {

    if($file.LastWriteTime -gt ($date).AddHours($hours)) {

        #get parent directory name
        $parent = Split-Path $file.DirectoryName -Leaf

        if($parent -eq 'STG') {
            (Get-Content $dest_file\STG\BatFile.txt) | Foreach-Object {
                $_ -replace 'dev', 'stg' `
                #Format: -replace 'SOMETHING', 'SOMETHING ELSE' `
            } | Set-Content $dest_file
        } elseif($parent -eq 'PRD') {
            (Get-Content $dest_file\PRD\BatFile.txt) | Foreach-Object {
                $_ -replace 'dev', 'stg' `
                #Format: -replace 'SOMETHING', 'SOMETHING ELSE' `
            } | Set-Content $dest_file
        }
    }
} else {
    $LogDestination = 'C:\FakeEnv\Logs'
    $LogPathExist = Test-Path "$LogDestination"        
    if($LogPathExist -eq $false) {
        New-Item $LogDestination -ItemType directory
        New-Item $LogDestination\log.log -ItemType file
        Add-Content $LogDestination\log.log "Script detected no changes in $dest_file on $date"
    } else {
        Add-Content $LogDestination\log.log "`nScript detected no changes in $dest_file on $date"
    }
}
```

Also, try to keep your indentation consistent.

Comment: it is at least getting through the logic now, but I get access denied on the set-content portion: Set-Content : Access to the path 'C:\FakeEnv\DEVbox' is denied.

Comment: I did not look for other errors you will have to debug more ... (or try with `-Force` and admin rights)